# Searching for effective way to store graph with 3 million vertices in MySQL

Tags: mysql, graph, data-mining, graph-algorithm, graph-databases

The goal is to make many cycled chains in graph with 3 million vertices.

The question is how to store edges in MySQL database and maintain fast speed, searching cycled chains, using Dijkstra's algorithm may be?

Comment: Does it have to be in MySQL? Can't you use a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database)?

Comment: I can use it. Can you suggest some PHP implementation?

Comment: How dense is the graph? What is the average number of edges per vertex?

Comment: Most vertices has 10-50 edges, some of them (near 100 may be) has 10000-50000 edges.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a job for a graph database. [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) is an excellent choice.